# Flask Login is not working properly on Python Anywhere

Tags: flask, pythonanywhere

This morning I tried to login in my account from my website(deployed on pythonanywhere

After that, I tried to login from my main device. It worked perfectly. I checked if I entered the same credentials and I did.

The view function:

```
@application.route('/logmein', methods=['POST'])
def logmein():

    password = request.form['password']
    email = request.form['email']

    user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
    spass = check_password_hash(user.password, password)

    if not user:
        return '<h1>We could not find the account!<a href="/login">try again</a></h1>'
    else:
        if spass == True:

           login_user(user, remember=True)
           return redirect('/')
        else:
           return '<body style="background: yellow"><h1>The password is incorrect! <a href="/login"> go back</a></h1></body>'
```

Thanks for help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see whats being sent over when you post by printing the form data.

```py
@application.route('/logmein', methods=['POST'])
def logmein():
    print(request.form)

    # print each method so you can look around
    print(dir(request.form))
    return 'test'
```

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'password'` < Leads me to beleive the issue is that password doesnt exist as you reference it.